# How to resolve ERR_CACHE_MISS with PHP after using back button?

Tags: php, header

I have a page on my website that contains several sorting buttons.

I would like to avoid ERR_CACHE_MISS error in the eventuality that the user tries to click back after using them.

I tried this :

```
header('Cache-Control: no cache');
```

It works fine after one sort only, but it doesn't work after several sorts.

So I tried this :

```
header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/currentpage.php');
```

It doesn't work at all, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: This is often caused by a POST, could you just switch to a GET instead?

Comment: Is there a way to use GET instead of POST without parameter in the URL ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But is there private stuff in the URL, or does it just look ugly?